# как сделать так чтобы пароль находился в файле , никого my sql

Tags: php, файлы, авторизация, nosql, пароль

как сделать так чтобы пароль находился в файле а не в авторизации
пароль у меня sfm но как сделать , чтобы вот этот пароль был в файле
вот что не хочу: чтобы пароль не хранился в файле auth.php хочу чтобы пароль хранился в файле login.txt  как это сделать?  [image: не хочу] [image: хочу , файл: login.txt]

вот код кстати:

```
<?php
$PASSWORD = 'sfm';
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['_sfm_allowed1']) {
    // sha1, and random bytes to thwart timing attacks.  Not meant as secure hashing.
    $t = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10));  
    if($_POST['p'] && sha1($t.$_POST['p']) === sha1($t.$PASSWORD)) {
        $_SESSION['_sfm_allowed1'] = true;
        header('Location: ?');
    }
    echo '<html><body><form action=? method=post>PASSWORD:<input type=password name=p /></form></body></html>'; 
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php

// $PASSWORD = 'sfm';
$PASSWORD = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'login.txt');
```

Главное не забудьте запретить доступ к файлу `login.txt` из веб. А лучше положите его на уровень выше док-рута (и поменяйте путь к нему в скрипте)

Comment: все работает и спасибо за советы все работает